# Filter data column has certain word

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
ID    Value
1    {"user_id":112312}
2    {"email":#####@gmail.com, "phone":#######578}
3    {"email":#####@gmail.com}
4    {"user_id":234242}
```

I want to filter this dataframe and keep rows which have "email" in column Value. So desired result is:

```
ID    Value
2    {"email":#####@gmail.com}
3    {"email":#####@gmail.com}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using dplyr to filter rows which contain partial string of column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239272/using-dplyr-to-filter-rows-which-contain-partial-string-of-column)

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
dataframe %>% filter(across(Value, ~ grepl('email', .)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` solution would be:

```
#Code
df2 <- df[grepl('email',df$Value),]
```

Output:

```
  ID                                         Value
2  2 {"email":#####@gmail.com, "phone":#######578}
3  3                     {"email":#####@gmail.com}
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Value = c("{\"user_id\":112312}", 
"{\"email\":#####@gmail.com, \"phone\":#######578}", "{\"email\":#####@gmail.com}", 
"{\"user_id\":234242}")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subset those rows containing `"email"` parts and then extract the pattern of emails.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Value, "email")) %>% 
  mutate(Value = str_c('{', str_extract(Value, '"email[^,}]+'), '}'))

#   ID                     Value
# 1  2 {"email":#####@gmail.com}
# 2  3 {"email":#####@gmail.com}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like this is coming from JSON data and it is probably best to parse it properly when you first load it.  Try the package `jsonlite`.

In lieu of this, you can try the following hack to drop the phone data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Value = c("{\"user_id\":112312}", 
                                                   "{\"email\":#####@gmail.com, \"phone\":#######578}", "{\"email\":#####@gmail.com}", 
                                                   "{\"user_id\":234242}")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Value = str_sub(Value, 2, -2),
         Value = str_split(Value, ",", simplify = FALSE)) %>% 
  unnest(Value) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Value, "email")) %>% 
  mutate(Value = paste0("{",Value,"}"))
```

I am using the data structure from the answer by @Duck.